# why type=channel not working in YouTube.search.list?

Tags: python-3.x, youtube, youtube-data-api

when I am not using type=channel this code works fine but otherwise it returns 400 error . I really want this code to run because I want to get the channels list that were made during covid 19 in Pakistan.
[https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?apix_params=%7B"part"%3A%5B"snippet"%5D%2C"location"%3A"30.3753%2C%2069.3451"%2C"locationRadius"%3A"1km"%2C"order"%3A"date"%2C"publishedAfter"%3A"2019-11-01T00%3A00%3A00Z"%2C"publishedBefore"%3A"2021-11-01T00%3A00%3A00Z"%2C"q"%3A"business"%2C"regionCode"%3A"PK"%2C"type"%3A%5B"channel"%5D%7D](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%22%5D%2C%22location%22%3A%2230.3753%2C%2069.3451%22%2C%22locationRadius%22%3A%221km%22%2C%22order%22%3A%22date%22%2C%22publishedAfter%22%3A%222019-11-01T00%3A00%3A00Z%22%2C%22publishedBefore%22%3A%222021-11-01T00%3A00%3A00Z%22%2C%22q%22%3A%22business%22%2C%22regionCode%22%3A%22PK%22%2C%22type%22%3A%5B%22channel%22%5D%7D)

Comment: Please provide your code and correct the link you have put in the question. Your question is not clear.

Comment: I think this is an issue with the API itself. Check in [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803) and see it other had posted a similar issue, or post the issue yourself.

Comment: If channel is optional, use `video` - see this [working example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%22%5D%2C%22location%22%3A%2230.3753%2C%2069.3451%22%2C%22locationRadius%22%3A%221km%22%2C%22order%22%3A%22date%22%2C%22publishedAfter%22%3A%222019-11-01T00%3A00%3A00Z%22%2C%22publishedBefore%22%3A%222021-11-01T00%3A00%3A00Z%22%2C%22q%22%3A%22business%22%2C%22regionCode%22%3A%22PK%22%2C%22type%22%3A%5B%22video%22%5D%7D)